# Use XPath to update versionCode in Android Manifest

Tags: xml, xpath, continuous-integration, android-manifest

In my CI pipeline I want to use XPath to automatically up rev my app version. I've managed to do this for the Info.plist for the iOS version, but that task does not use XPath. I can access the manifest file itself and add values to different sections of the manifest, but not the versionCode, versionName etc.

There's not too much in the way that I can find of online resources to update the versionName using XPath.

Here's my latest attempt at trying to access it;

```
    JsonPatchContent: '= /manifest/[@android:name:versionName]/@android:value => $(NewVersionNumber)'
```

$NewVersionNumber is a variable that lives in the pipeline that uses a counter to increase by 1 during each build. I need that number to replace whatever is currently stored in versionName

Answer (score 0):

As *android* is a namespace declaration, it's URL must be declared. The trick is that your XPath query must match **exactly** what it is you are trying to access rather than a loose basis of it.

`'= /manifest/@android:versionName => "$(AppVersionNumber)"'`